# Can't open saved plot until I restart RStudio

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

When I save a plot like this:

```
png("test.png")
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
```

I'm sometimes unable to open the file until I restart RStudio.  Windows 10 gives me the error message:

> "It looks like you don't have permission to view this file.  Check the
>   permissions and try again."

How can I open the file in another application without restarting RStudio and losing my environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a graphics device open from a previous command (the code above is not causing the problem, but is where it manifests).  [RStudio guidance suggests](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488548-Problem-with-Plots-or-Graphics-Device):

> To reset your graphics device, call the following code from the
>   console:
>
> > `dev.off()`
>
> Note:
>
> This will delete your current plots in the RStudio Plots Pane. **If you
>   have multiple graphics devices open, repeat this command until the
>   output displays null device.**

Run `dev.off()` repeatedly until it returns "null device."